# Merge array of hashes with addition

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes

```
hash = [{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"2"},
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"8"}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"4"}, 
{"user"=>"11245", "count"=>"3"}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"2"}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"7"}, 
{"user"=>"11245", "count"=>"2"}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"1"}, 
{"user"=>"13869", "count"=>"2"}]
```

I am trying to find a way to merge this into a new array of hashes where each user appears only once, with a count that is the sum of all the counts associated with the user previously.

The above should result in the following hash:

```
newhash = [{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>"24"},
{"user"=>"11245", "count"=>"5"}, 
{"user"=>"13869", "count"=>"2"}]
```

I tried a long complex method that just loops over it many times to combine hashes, but I can't make it work. There must be a better, simpler way.

Comment: Please show us your **long complex method**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hash
.to_enum.with_object(Hash.new(0)){|e, h| h[e["user"]] += e["count"].to_i}
.map{|k, v| {"user" => k, "count" => v.to_s}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works really nicely. I'm impressed by how short it is.

Comment: Any particular reason for `hash.to_enum.with_object...` rather than `hash.each_with_object...`? Would `hash` have been your choice for the name of an array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The OP assigns the array to variable `hash`. It is misleading though. As for not using `each_with_object`, I like the decomposed one.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this.

```
grouped = hash.group_by{|h| h['user']}
grouped.map do |user_id, user| 
  total = user.reduce(0) { |sum, h| sum+=h['count'].to_i }
  {'user'=> user_id, 'count'=> total.to_s}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like:

```
hash = [{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>2},
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>8}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>4}, 
{"user"=>"11245", "count"=>3}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>2}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>7}, 
{"user"=>"11245", "count"=>2}, 
{"user"=>"10910", "count"=>1}, 
{"user"=>"13869", "count"=>2}]

merged = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {"user" => k, "count" => 0} }
hash.each { |x| merged[x["user"]]["count"] += x["count"] }

newhash = merged.values
```